# Paint on tubs please help

Tags: shower

I'm a housekeeper and we are remodeling our entire hotel. The painters have gotten paint on the tubs. I can get the paint off the walls of the tub no problem. What can I use to get the paint off the floor of the tub. I can't scrape it off because the tub is textured (to prevent slipping)

Comment: What type of tub are these cast iron, fiberglass, Molded poly?

Comment: What type of paint was used?

Answer (score 2):

if its latex paint, it will come off with a paint remover like goo be gone or goof off, if its oil paint, you can use brake fluid.  either approach will mean letting the liquid sit on the paint for a few hours or overnight.

however, as both will not damage enameled steel tubs, either can damage acrylic, fiberglass or epoxied tubs, but it depends on the model and what/how its made.  i would probably do a test on a single tub in a single unit to make sure it won't destroy the underlying finish.

when all done, clean the area with a good degreaser and then some plain white vinegar (to neutralize the alkalinity of the degreaser)

hope that helps